# For loop using names of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lag

I am working with COVID-19 data from my country by regions (3) in a dataframe. I want to use those columns of positive cases to generate other columns in which I want to calculate the growth in between rows. The dataframe:

```
> df
  Lima Arequipa Huánuco
1    1       NA      NA
2    6       NA      NA
3    6        1      NA
4    8        2       5
5    9        3       7
6    11       4       8
```

I want to use a for loop to calculate in a new column named as each df's column adding to its name "_dif" in which I have the `row 1 - lag (row 1)` for each column. So I used this code:

```
for(col in names(df)) {
  df[paste0(col, "_dif")] = df[col] - lag(df[col])
}
```

The output I want is the next one:

```
  Lima Arequipa Huánuco Lima_dif Arequipa_dif Huánuco_dif
1    1       NA      NA       NA           NA          NA
2    6       NA      NA       5            NA          NA
3    6        1      NA       0            NA          NA
4    8        2       5       2            1           NA
5    9        3       7       1            1           2
6    11       4       8       2            1           1
```

But when I see the df after the for loop I got this (only NA in the new columns):

```
  Lima Arequipa Huánuco Lima_dif Arequipa_dif Huánuco_dif
1    1       NA      NA       NA           NA          NA
2    6       NA      NA       NA           NA          NA
3    6        1      NA       NA           NA          NA
4    8        2       5       NA           NA          NA
5    9        3       7       NA           NA          NA
6    11       4       8       NA           NA          NA
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `mutate` with `across` from `dplyr` as the `_all/_at` suffixes are getting deprecated and in the newer version, `across` is more genneralized

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ . - lag(.), names = "{col}_dif"))
#   Lima Arequipa Huánuco Lima_dif Arequipa_dif Huánuco_dif
#1    1       NA      NA       NA           NA          NA
#2    6       NA      NA        5           NA          NA
#3    6        1      NA        0           NA          NA
#4    8        2       5        2            1          NA
#5    9        3       7        1            1           2
#6   11        4       8        2            1           1
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df[paste0(names(df), "_dif")] <- lapply(df, function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
```

Or another option is

```
df[paste0(names(df), "_dif")] <- rbind(NA, diff(as.matrix(df)))
```

---

The issue in the OP's `for` loop is that `df[col]` is a still a `data.frame` with a single column, we need `df[[col]]` to extract as `vector` because `lag` needs a `vector`. According to `?lag`

> x - Vector of values

```
lag(df[1])
#  Lima
#1   NA
```

returns `NA` and it gets recycled

while,

```
lag(df[[1]])
#[1] NA  1  6  6  8  9
```

therefore, if we change the code to

```
for(col in names(df)) {
  df[paste0(col, "_dif")] = df[[col]] - lag(df[[col]])
 }


df
#  Lima Arequipa Huánuco Lima_dif Arequipa_dif Huánuco_dif
#1    1       NA      NA       NA           NA          NA
#2    6       NA      NA        5           NA          NA
#3    6        1      NA        0           NA          NA
#4    8        2       5        2            1          NA
#5    9        3       7        1            1           2
#6   11        4       8        2            1           1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Lima = c(1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L), Arequipa = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Huánuco = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 8L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: The last part solved the problem. Despite of that, the other solutions were interesting. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, you can use `mutate_all` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate_all(list(diff = ~. - lag(.)))

#  Lima Arequipa Huánuco Lima_diff Arequipa_diff Huánuco_diff
#1    1       NA      NA        NA            NA           NA
#2    6       NA      NA         5            NA           NA
#3    6        1      NA         0            NA           NA
#4    8        2       5         2             1           NA
#5    9        3       7         1             1            2
#6   11        4       8         2             1            1
```

Or `shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (paste0(names(df), '_diff')) := .SD - shift(.SD)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

```
df <- read_table("V  Lima  Arequipa    Huanuco
1    1       NA      NA
2    6       NA      NA
3    6        1      NA
4    8        2       5
5    9        3       7
6    11       4       8")

for(col in names(df)) {
  df[paste0(col, "_dif")] <- df[col] - lag(df[col], default = 0)
}
df

# A tibble: 6 x 8
      V  Lima Arequipa Huanuco V_dif Lima_dif Arequipa_dif Huanuco_dif
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1     1       NA      NA     1        1           NA          NA
2     2     6       NA      NA     2        6           NA          NA
3     3     6        1      NA     3        6            1          NA
4     4     8        2       5     4        8            2           5
5     5     9        3       7     5        9            3           7
6     6    11        4       8     6       11            4           8
```

You didn't set `lag`'s default to 0, so it went to NA.

Comment: It works but this solution generate that when the first number of a column (after the NA) subtracts the lag one (for example: `9 (actual one) - NA (lag one)` the code gives me 9 and it should be NA. Thank you very much.